# Favicon plugin for WordPress running in network mode (multisite)?

Tags: multisite, network-admin, favicon

What favicon plugin should I use in order to define favicons for Wordpress when I run in multi-site mode.

Uploading favicon.ico files is not an option for multi-site wordpress instances.

I am looking for something simple that will not pollute the generated pages with hidden advertising.

**EDIT:** Looking to be able to define favicons on a per site basis. Different favicons for different sites.

Comment: You shouldn't have to use a plugin for this.
A favicon should be part of every WordPress theme by default

Comment: Have you ever used WordPress in network mode? I do not want to customize themes and have to manually upload favicons to strange locations in order to make this work.

Comment: No, favicons absolutely should NOT be a part of every WordPress Theme. A favicon is personal/site branding, and should be treated as user data/content that is separate from the Theme. Themes may change, but a user presumably wants the favicon to remain the same.

Comment: I ported a Favicon Plugin, but haven't touched it in a while. Maybe I should go back and make sure it's network-aware, and clean it up/ simplify it a bit.

Comment: What I mean is, it just a matter of uploading a favicon.ico file to the root of the installation. Then the <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" /> code will show the favicon

Comment: @stffn - it is clear that you have no idea on how wordpress works in network mode. I was asking about a solution that would allow me to define different favicons for each site.

Comment: BTW, there are tons of Favicons plugins on wordpress, and due to this I asked witch one is maintained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I am successfully using [All In One Favincon](http://www.techotronic.de/plugins/all-in-one-favicon/) Plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [Shockingly Simple Favicon](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/shockingly-simple-favicon/).  I am using this on my multisite installation.